# How is an unprivileged terminal able to signal interrupt to a process launched via sudo as another user?

Tags: terminal, signals

See for yourself:

```
% sudo sleep 100 &
[1] 23272
% pkill sleep
pkill: killing pid 23275 failed: Operation not permitted
% fg
[1]  + running    sudo sleep 100
^C
%
```

How is it that the terminal is able to terminate the privileged `sleep` process here?

I verified and ascertained two things:

- It is forbidden to signal to processes that belong to any other user, even to `nobody`.

  ```
  % sudo -u nobody sleep 100 &
  [1] 24321
  % pkill sleep
  pkill: killing pid 24324 failed: Operation not permitted
  ```

  I tried this with `SIGTERM`, `SIGKILL` and `SIGINT` — none get delivered.
- Ctrl+C does send the SIGINT.

  ```
  % cat script.sh
  #!/bin/sh

  trap 'echo "SIGINT caught!"' SIGINT

  while true
  do
      sleep 1
  done
  % ./script.sh
  ^CSIGINT caught!
  ```

So it does look like we have a contradiction here.

Comment: See `Signal handling` section in `man sudo`.

Comment: contradiction with what? when you press Control-C (`VINTR`), it's the kernel which is sending the `SIGINT` signal to the foreground job, not some userland process, privileged or not.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk It says it relays signals. But `sudo` is itself running as `root`, so how does it receive those signals in the first place?

Comment: @mosvy Contradiction between that I cannot signal to a process that runs as another user without being root myself and that I can signal a process running as another user via unprivileged terminal. Why do I feel like you are trying to be condescending rather than helpful? If you have something to say, then go ahead and write a useful answer.

Comment: I have no idea why you feel like that, or why you assume that I'm talking out of my ass when I tell you that it's the kernel which is sending the signal. I don't want to interract further, but I have news for you -- you can not only signal the process, but "fake" its standard input via the "unprivileged terminal".